# co.elastic.clients.transport.TransportException: [es/search] Missing [X-Elastic-Product] header

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm following the tutorial from elastic search java api client here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/connecting.html

My code is as following.

```
// Create the low-level client
RestClient restClient = RestClient.builder(
 new HttpHost("localhost", 9200)).build();

// Create the transport with a Jackson mapper
ElasticsearchTransport transport = new RestClientTransport(
 restClient, new JacksonJsonpMapper());

// And create the API client
ElasticsearchClient client = new ElasticsearchClient(transport);

try {
 SearchResponse<Object> search = client.search(s -> s
   .index("*:*"),
   Object.class);
} catch (IOException e) {
 System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

This code is throwing out the following exception:

```
co.elastic.clients.transport.TransportException: [es/search] Missing [X-Elastic-Product] header. Please check that you are connecting to an Elasticsearch instance, and that any networking filters are preserving that header.
```

I've tried manually putting this header via the `setDefaultHeaders` method like this:

```
RestClientBuilder builder = RestClient.builder(
 new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http"));
Header[] defaultHeaders = new Header[]{new BasicHeader("X-Elastic-Product", "Elasticsearch")};
builder.setDefaultHeaders(defaultHeaders);
RestClient restClient = builder.build();
```

But the error is the same.

I've tried both version 7.16 and 8.0.0, same result.

Comment: are you sure you are also running an Elasticsearch server (not API) version >= 7.16 ?

Comment: I ran into the same problem... have you found any solution? I am using he new java client 8.4 on an elasticsearch server 7.10. I've set compatibility headers. Indexing of a document works fine. When I perform a get request for a given index and id this problem arise

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The default headers the `RestClientBuilder` allows you to specify are the *request* headers, not the response headers. The error you are getting is because older Elasticsearch [server] versions do not include the `X-Elastic-Product=Elasticsearch` header in any of the API responses, but the recent distributions do (7.14+?), so the newer versions of `elasticsearch-java` (i.e. client) expects them.

I am in the same boat — I use 8.4.2 of `elasticsearch-java` with an Elasticsearch server version of 7.2.0.

I ran into two format-based compatibility issues:

1. The client passing a `Content-Type` not known to the server, and so its request getting rejected with a 406
2. The client validating if the response has `X-Elastic-Product=Elasticsearch` header

Fortunately, the `RestClientBuilder` allows you to customize the underlying http client through: `setHttpClientConfigCallback`. The callback looks like this, so basically you can intercept the request and responses, manipulate headers, and thereby get around these issues:

```
    public interface HttpClientConfigCallback {
        /**
         * Allows to customize the {@link CloseableHttpAsyncClient} being created and used by the {@link RestClient}.
         * Commonly used to customize the default {@link org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider} for authentication
         * or the {@link SchemeIOSessionStrategy} for communication through ssl without losing any other useful default
         * value that the {@link RestClientBuilder} internally sets, like connection pooling.
         */
        HttpAsyncClientBuilder customizeHttpClient(HttpAsyncClientBuilder httpClientBuilder);
    }
```

Specifically, here's what worked for me:

```
var httpClientConfigCallback = httpClientBuilder ->
        httpClientBuilder
            .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
            // this request & response header manipulation helps get around newer (>=7.16) versions
            // of elasticsearch-java client not working with older (<7.14) versions of Elasticsearch
            // server
            .setDefaultHeaders(
                List.of(
                    new BasicHeader(
                        HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString())))
            .addInterceptorLast(
                (HttpResponseInterceptor)
                    (response, context) ->
                        response.addHeader("X-Elastic-Product", "Elasticsearch"));
var restClient =
        RestClient.builder(elasticsearchHosts)
            .setHttpClientConfigCallback(httpClientConfigCallback)
            .build();
```

Note that there could still be behavioral differences between the aforementioned product and API versions as they are way too apart. The above only fixes format-based incompatibilities. For this reason, it's always best to use at least the same major versions of these components, if not the exact versions.

Comment: can you share full client config code?

Answer (score 2):

Below is what worked for me. I hope it helps someone out there

```
@Configuration
public class config {
    @Bean
    public RestClient getRestClient() {
        final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials("", ""));
        return RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost", 9500))
                .setHttpClientConfigCallback(httpClientBuilder -> {
                    httpClientBuilder.disableAuthCaching();
                    httpClientBuilder.setDefaultHeaders(List.of(
                            new BasicHeader(
                                    HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON)));
                    httpClientBuilder.addInterceptorLast((HttpResponseInterceptor)
                            (response, context) ->
                                    response.addHeader("X-Elastic-Product", "Elasticsearch"));
                    return httpClientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
                }).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchTransport getElasticsearchTransport() {
        return new RestClientTransport(getRestClient(), new JacksonJsonpMapper());
    }

    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchClient getElasticsearchClient() {
        return new ElasticsearchClient(getElasticsearchTransport());
    }

}
```

Comment: Waw, it works
but your port is not default 9200
`return RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost", 9200))`