# Elasticsearch POST /my-index/_count error 406 Not Acceptable

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I'm using elasticsearch-java-client 7.17.4 to make my a count request to AWS Elasticsearch server like this follow code

```
elasticsearchClient.count(s -> s
    .index("my-index")
).count();
```

However the follow exception was happening

```
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [POST], 
host [https://my-host], URI [/my-index/_count], status line [HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable]
{"error":"Content-Type header [application/vnd.elasticsearch+json; compatible-with=8] is not supported","status":406}
```

Looking [_count api at elasticsearch RestAPI reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-count.html) sound like strange because the http method is GET, but elasticsearch-java make a request with POST.

Somebody had this issue?

Comment: What the version lib Java Client API?

Comment: I try with 7.17.4 and 8.2.2. Both make _count with POST instead GET.

Answer (score 4):

I forgot a important part, the response body are saying

```
{"error":"Content-Type header [application/vnd.elasticsearch+json; compatible-with=8] 
is not supported","status":406}
```

**Solution**

```
RestClient restClient = RestClient
    .builder(new HttpHost(url, port, scheme))
    .setDefaultHeaders(new Header[]{
        new BasicHeader("Content-type", "application/json")
    })
    .build();
```

Comment: I saw this solution but as my versions were working I didn't recommend it.
If yours is working now it's great too.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the Java Client API to version 8.2.2.
I tested with Java Client API v8.2.2. and ElasticSearch v7.17.1 and it worked.

Comment: I try to use 8.2.2 but same problem. My Elasticsearch Server is 7.10. It's strange the RestAPI reference expressly method GET but Java Client API make POST.

Comment: Here code that prepare the request https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-java/blob/df8ba67f1f0471ddd4363a7c80e53ef23e305963/java-client/src/main/java/co/elastic/clients/elasticsearch/core/CountRequest.java#L625

Comment: It's my bad Andre. I forgot a important part from error. Thanks for help.

Comment: I got the same problem and the answer of Rabbitbr did not solve my problem but gave me a nice clue to solve my issue.

In my case I was using Elasticsearch 7.7.0 and the org.elasticsearch.client/elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client version 7.17.15. I only upgraded my Elasticsearch from 7.7.0 to 7.17.15 and it went well.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. However, my problem related to the version of the elasticsearch. We have some obligation to use only the `7.10.2`. And I use the version of `co.elastic.clients:elasticsearch-java:8.9.0` and `scala org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.12.13`

After I fixed the problem with Content-type, I got another problem with the `X-Elastic-Product`. So I must do another fix to work with a specific elasticsearch version.

This answer helps me: [co.elastic.clients.transport.TransportException: [es/search] Missing [X-Elastic-Product] header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71142680/co-elastic-clients-transport-transportexception-es-search-missing-x-elastic)

```java
    val client: RestClient = RestClient
      .builder(HttpHost.create(s"$node"))
      .setHttpClientConfigCallback(httpClientConfigCallback =>
        httpClientConfigCallback
          .addInterceptorLast((response: HttpResponse, _: HttpContext) =>
            response.addHeader("X-Elastic-Product", "Elasticsearch")))
      .setDefaultHeaders(Array(new BasicHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString)))
      .build()
```